# Non- brown, blue,green eye colour genotypes and genes

Tags: genetics, human-eye

In genetics, eye colours (brown, green and blue) are determined by bey2 and gey genes. But what about hazel, grey and amber and more? I read a webpage about hazel eye colour and saw that there is a 3rd gene called 'hey' with 'codes' H and h
Other than B(brown), G(green) and b(blue) but now what does H and h mean when there is one hazel?

Comment: Welcome to Biology StackExchange! According to the [guidelines](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) of this site, your question might seem a little bit under-researched. You should also provide references to your statements. For example: _"eye colours are determined by bey2 and gey genes"_ is not an accurate statement because (as you can read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_color)) _"The genetics and inheritance of eye color in humans is **complicated**"_ and _"So far, **as many as 15 genes** have been associated with eye color inheritance"_.

Comment: Therefore, I suggest you read some more (online) resources on this topic, and then try to edit your question into a more detailed and focused one, along with the references you have read :-) There are also some useful answers on this StackExchange, such as [Why are human eye colours limited?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10041/why-are-human-eye-colours-limited) and [How is eye color in humans inherited?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/728/how-is-eye-color-in-humans-inherited).